# Python pytesseract incorrect text extraction from image

Tags: python, python-2.7, tesseract, pytesser, python-tesseract

I'm trying to extract the text from image using pytesseract.
But I'm getting incorrect text.
suppose when I try to read the following image,

```
A = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('A.png'),config='-psm 6',lang = 'eng')
```

output is:

```
Shooﬁng
```

I mentioned the language 'English' but still getting unknown characters like "**ﬁ**" 
[image]

Though I mentioned lang= 'eng', it is giving latin characters.

**"ﬁ"**

Name : Latin Small Ligature Fi
Unicode number
U+FB01

Comment: I found that those characters are from Latin  language( ﬂ ,ﬁ). Is there any way to ignore those chars

Comment: What version of Tesseract are you using?  I just tried your image using 4.00.00alpha and it returned the correct text.

Comment: pytesseract==0.2.0 python 2.7

Comment: Is there any way to ignore other language Unicode characters?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am having this problem.